# Query and combine sorted paginated results from multiple tables effectively

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a hierarchy of members - *organisations* and *users*. An organisation may contain other organisations or users. An organisation or user is a member of just one organization (1:N). The hierarchy is stored in table **member**. Table **organisation** contains data of organisations and **user** contains data of users:

```
CREATE TABLE member(
    member_id CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    parent_member_id CHARACTER VARYING(255),
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE organization (
    member_id CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    name CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE user (
    member_id CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    username CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    first_name CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

I need to create an endpoint that would return a sorted paginated list of direct members of a certain member. The returned list should contain a mixture of organisations and users. I use spring data (JPARepository). The easiest way I could achieve it is to make a query to table **organisation** (using join on member), then make a query to table **user** (using join on member) and then combine the resultsets. But multiple sequential queries doesn't seem much effective. Is there a better way? For example replacing two queries by parallel queries? Or obtaining the resultset in a single query? Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join strategy` in `JPA` inheritance. Create a class `Member` for `member` table and two classes `User` for `users` table and `Organization` for `organizations` table that extends `Member` class.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Member {
    @Id
    public String memberId;
    @ManyToOne
    public Member parentMember;

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class User extends Member {
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Organization extends Member {
    private String name;

    //getters and setters
}
```

then create a `Spring Data Repository` for `Member` class:

```
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<Member, String> {
    List<Member> findByParentMember(Member parent);
    Page<Member> findByParentMember(Member parent, Pagable pageable);
}
```

This way hibernate will return all the members (users and organizations) by creating a single join query between all 3 tables instead of two joined queries between two tables.